# Is Google monitering my adsense code for account activation

Tags: adsense

What I have done is:

1. Created adsense account
2. Created an ad unit
3. Placed that ad unit code on my website
4. After few days I removed that adsense code from my website
5. Now when I open my adsense account the following page is displayed:
   [image]

And when I again submit request for account approval, I receive email with status:

> Site does not comply with Google policies

And in recommendations:

```
Don’t place ads on auto-generated pages or pages with little to no original content.
```

Now my question is:

Is Google evaluting my website on the basis of adsense code? If yes how can I get the code again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Google is monitoring *everything* you do.

Comment: How can i get the code again?

Comment: Event I can't remove this account to create a new one

Comment: @SergioTulentsev this is a real problem that I'm facing. I need an alternative. I have asked this in google forums as well but no response

Comment: @IrfanWattoo: real as it may be, it's still off-topic.